# A cauchy sequence with an unbounded subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Does there exist a Cauchy sequence with an unbounded subsequence?

I know that all Cauchy sequences are bounded, so my guess is no.
If there is, can someone provide me an example?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is negative. A real sequence converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence. Every convergent sequence is bounded. If a sequence is a Cauchy sequence, it has to be bounded and it cannot have an unbounded subsequence.

Comment: thx, I'm new to sequence and limits